# sqlite: how to update a column with results from subquery?

Tags: sqlite, count

I need to update a column containing the number of duplicated values of the same tableA.
The query for duplicates is easy but how to update a column with its results?

This is what my modest sql knowledge brought me to:

```
with dupl as (
select "KGEZ" as k, count(*) as c from tableA group by "KGEZ" having c>1
)
update tableA
set "kgez_count" = "c"
where  "KGEZ" = "k"
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you want:

```
with dupl as (
  select "KGEZ" as k, count(*) as c from tableA group by "KGEZ" having c > 1
)
update tableA
set "kgez_count" = coalesce((select c from dupl where k = tableA."KGEZ"), 0)
```

I use `coalesce()` just in case there are no duplicates for a `"KGEZ"` if you don't want that column to be updated to `null`.